# Does readable.push() maintain a buffer in memory?

Tags: node.js, node-streams

The documentation says that invoking `readable.push(chunk)` will cause data to be added to the **internal queue** for users to consume. Does that mean there is an internal buffer in the memory writing data until the buffer gets full, each time `readable.push(chunk)` gets invoked?

```
var Readable = require("stream").Readable;

var readable = new Readable();

var num = 1;

readable._read = function(size) {
    readable.push((num++).toString());
    if (num == 101) {
        readable.push(null);
    }
}

readable.pipe(process.stdout);
```

If that's what actually happens, can you explain me how the writable stream `process.stdout` works with that internal buffer? I know it also maintains its own buffer in the memory.

I understand I might have gotten everything wrong here from the beginning, but I'm trying to put everything together until I make myself clear with this concept.

Thanks!

Comment: `process.stdout` is pretty easy to drain, it just prints stuff, so the buffer doesn't have to be big. As for the other one, depends on the particular internals. I don't know that the buffer ever "gets full", it just expands as necessary.

Comment: @tadman so that means we have two internals working together to print stuff to the `process.stdout` right?

Comment: I mean mostly in contrast to, say, a network output where you might not be able to write. There's not much that impedes your ability to dump to `stdout`. The process itself will get stuck in an IO wait state if it ever does flood it somehow.